# Arch Linux - pactree : command not found

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I have to list all dependencies of 71 packages. I planned to write a bash using [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1308034/recursively-list-dependencies-of-a-package-in-arch-linux/1320100#1320100) with a for loop but I got this message:

```
pactree : command not found
```

I have updated pacman but pactree still doesn't work. I searched in the arch repo and aur but both don't have pactree. What should I do to use pactree or at least list all dependencies?

Comment: I tried this ( $ expac -l '\n' %E -S [packages] | sort -u ) as the arch wiki suggested, but got the same error as pactree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pactree` is in the [pacman-contrib](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/pacman-contrib/) package now, not the pacman package.  `expac` is in an [expac](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/expac/) package.